# Scope of JQuery data element

Tags: jquery, asp.net

When does the data in the JQuery's `data` element expire? I want to store the data that I have in the `ViewState` object on a ASP.NET page in the `data` element so that I can avoid making several round trips to the server to grab this data (that I use for client side functions)

Comment: Expire? It expires when the object it's attached to expires...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `.data('foo','bar')` is [essentially] just an attribute `data-foo="bar"` applied to the element. So, as long as the element exists in the DOM, so does the data that's attached to it.

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish though, so can't be more specific. Maybe elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish (work-flow, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Think of the `data` function as attaching an attribute to a DOM element.  It vanishes when that attribute is removed or the element it's attached to is destroyed.

It does **not** use cookies.

Answer (score 0):

jquery.data() is a function, not an element. Since this function associates data with a DOM element, the data will be there until the DOM element is deleted from the page. As long as the element is in the page, the associated data to it will be available.

What kind of data are you trying to preserve here?